# React color animation synchronization

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have been using `react` to build out an editor. One of the configurable properties is to dynamically generate background color animation. For example, an infinite fade in and fade out with a `x` second period.

The problem is that the color animation needs to be same and synchronized in multiple views. CSS animations does not enable that synchronization without being hacky. I want to use 'react-motion' but it does not incorporate timing easily.

Looking for some concrete examples using react + react libraries (ideally react-motion). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing quite a bit of research into all of this, it turns out that the answer is just working at the animation frame level.

CSS animations abstracts all of this away from devs but as a result it gives very little control between animations.

React Motion `react-motion` while a good library for dealing with transition animations (it's intended purpose) again does not address controls between animations.

They key though exists in the `react-motion` code. You just have to request animation frames one after the other using `raf` library and then calculate the animations per view using the common frame info. It's pretty tedious and no real generic solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your request for examples using react + react libraries, but, if you're rendering on the client/browser you can use a global var for keeping sync between views. If that is too "hacky" for you, then perhaps finding a common parent up the ladder that both views can be handed a synchronized var/value.